# du command not displaying correctly

Tags: linux, du

I've been trying to get PHP to list the size of a directory for a while now. I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried a few other solutions and the only thing that works -somewhat- is the du command. I can get it to give me the directory size, but it's not correct. I'm trying to use the GoDaddy hosting. On a different (local) Linux machine I can run du on the same files and it gives me 72kb, but on the GoDaddy server it gives me 88kb. I can't seem to find out how to fix this and I've been searching for hours. Please help.

Edit: I have tried du --apparent-size

Comment: Bytes are bytes, but with the advent for LVMs, 512-4096 sectors and all other types of wizardry in virtual hosting, I'm not surprised that one environment may report a slightly different size than another. Do you have the filesystem details for the remote on godaddy?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin what kind of file system details?

Comment: Whether it is a straight unencrypted ext3/4, btrfs, xjs, over partitions and disks or any of those over an LVM encrypted volume, etc.. If you are seeing the roughly 20% diff in sizes, I would suspect that one side or the other is using either some type of encryption/compression or both that isn't a 1-to-1 match. Why `du` is having trouble? It may not be. If the compression/encryption is pronounced enough, it may be storing the exact size it sees on each machine. (would make it a bear to do a differential backup based on size, huh?)

Answer (score 1):

Here is [similar](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45771/df-vs-du-why-so-much-difference) question, check it for the differences if interpretation of disk usage data